# Best way to initialize a list of lists

Tags: performance, python-2.7, list, memory, initialization

Is there any difference in initializing a list of lists by

1. `[[0 for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(m)]`

or

2. `[[0]*n for j in xrange(m)]`

From the point of view of time performance the first way is 4 times faster than the second way, and I am wondering whether the first way has any computational/memory use or allocation drawback.

Comment: Hi @Ale. Not sure what you need this for, but maybe ask yourself if a `list` is the right data type. There's a chance that a `numpy.ndarray` is better for your application (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). One of the reasons is the fact that lists are mutable, so you'll have to know what you're doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I am just focusing on numpy-free methods. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
>   applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
>   some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
>   iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
>   certain condition.

First method is slower than the second method because a **no-op** is performed in each loop iteration.

P.S. If you want to initialise a list of list with constant value (k) then the ideal and the fastest way would be to used numpy `np.ones((m, n))*k`.

Comment: you should explain your statement in a better way.

Comment: @Mandar `l = [[0]*n]*m` is not the way at all. See what happens to that list after `l[0][0]=1`.